# jquery showhide issue

Tags: jquery, show-hide

i have 2 radio buttons, which when selected will show the relevant dropdown and hide the other one.

the problem is that the show/hide works fine for single clicks, but if i click on 'Carparks' to start, the Carparks dropdown appears; then select 'Buildings', and the Buildings drop down takes its place; however if i then click 'Carparks' again the Buildings dropdown stays and doesn't get replaced.

seems to only work once.

```
function hide(){
if(document.getElementById('buildings').checked) {
    $('#carParkDiv').removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');
    $('#buildingDiv').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
    $('input:radio[id="carparks"]').prop('checked', false);
}else if(document.getElementById('carparks').checked) {
  $('#carParkDiv').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
    $('#buildingDiv').removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');
    $('input:radio[id="buildings"]').attr('checked', false);
}
}


<input type="radio" name="whereto" id="buildings"  value="buildings" onchange="hide();"><label for="buildings">Buildings</label>
    <input type="radio" name="whereto" id="carparks"  value="carparks" onchange="hide();"><label for="carparks">Carparks</label><br>

    <div id="buildingDiv" class="hidden">
    <select id="buildingList" name="buildingList" onchange="addLocation();">
     <option>Buildings</option>
     <option value="B1">B1</option>
     <option value="B12">B12</option>
    </select> 
    </div>
    <div id="carParkDiv" class="hidden">
    <select id="carParkList" name="carParkList" onchange="addLocation();">
     <option>Car Parks</option>
     <option value="Visitor">Visitor</option>
     <option value="B">B</option>
     <option value="C">C</option>
     <option value="D">D</option>
    </select> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this once, also remove the `onchange` attribute from both the radio buttons:

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
    if ($('#buildings').is(':checked')) {
        $('#carParkDiv').removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');
        $('#buildingDiv').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
    } else if ($('#carparks').is(':checked')) {
        $('#carParkDiv').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
        $('#buildingDiv').removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EJzaK/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it muuuuuch more simply:
Just modify your DIV IDs to be similar to the values of your inputs:

E.g:

```
<input type="radio" name="whereto" id="carparks" value="carparks">
<div id="carparksDiv" class="hidden">...</div>
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uyilus/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('[name=whereto]:input').change(function(){
  if(this.checked){
      $('#'+ this.value +'Div').show().siblings('.hidden').hide();
  } 
});
```